# Misunderstanding middleware Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making a little social network using MongoDB, Express, NodeJS.
I have this Schema with a middleware to encrypt password.

```
const passwordValidators = [
    {
        validator: passwordLengthChecker,
        message: 'Password must be at least 5 characters but no more than 40'
    },
    {
        validator:validPassword,
        message: 'Must have at least one uppercase, lowercase, special character, and number'
    }
];


/* ========
Schema for user
========= */
const userSchema=new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true, validate: emailValidators},
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true, validate: usernameValidators},
    password: { type: String, required: true,validate: passwordValidators},
    bio: { type:String,default:null},
    location: {type:String, default:null},
    gender: {type:String,default:null},
    birthday: { type:Date,default:null},
    img: { type:String, default:null}
});


// Middleware that encrypt password 
userSchema.pre('save',function(next){
    if(!this.isModified('password'))
    return next();

    bcrypt.hash(this.password, null, null, (err,hash)=>{
        if(err) return next(err);
        this.password=hash;
        next();
    });
});
```

Now, I don't know if it's related, but everytime i use save() in my routes, this runs the passwordValidators.
I've read the mongoose doc, but I feel like I understand nothing about this. The solution I've guessed was to just skip this middleware when it's not registration, but I actually don't know how to do that.

Here's the route

```
router.post('/edit-photo', upload,function (req,res){
      if (!req.file) {
        res.json({success:false,message:"raté"});
      }
      else{
        User.findOne({_id:req.decoded.userId},(err,user)=>{
            if(err){
                res.json({success:false,message:'Something went wrong: '+err});
            }
            else{
                if (!user) {
                    res.json({success:false,message:'User not found'});
                }
                else{
                    user.img="Bloggy/uploads/profile/profile-pic-"+user.username;
                    user.save((err)=>{ // i get this err
                        if(err){
                            res.json({success:false,message:'Something went wrong: '+err});
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('réussi');
                }
            }
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that Mongoose runs every validators you make before save.

> Validation is middleware. Mongoose registers validation as a pre('save') hook on every schema by default.

In my case all I had to do was

```
user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false },(err)=>{
                        if(err){
                            res.json({success:false,message:'Something went wrong: '+err});
                        }
                        else{
                            res.json({success:true,message:"Update to databse"});
                        }
                    });
```

to skip validation for this route